# Global Class or Method to add THEAD and TBODY to GridVIew Site-wide automatically

Tags: c#, class, gridview, rendering, global-asax

I'm kinda new to C# and DotNet but I'm tryig to resolve an issue. I would like to create class that would reside in a global asax or as a cs file that can be called by a GridView's PreRender trigger to add the THEAD and TBODY feature to any gridview on a site. I have the code I want to use but I'm just not sure how to go about popping it into a global class or asax file so that all gridviews in a site render the THEAD, TBODY tags.

Can anyone help? I think this would be a useful tool for those that like to render their GridViews with the THEAD and TBODY tags.

Here is my code in C#:

```
protected void GridViewThead(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(GridView))
        {
            GridView Grid = (GridView)sender;
            if (Grid.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Grid.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                Grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                Grid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good reason to create a custom control that derives from `GridView`. You would add this functionality by overriding the `OnRender` method.